# How change color title MDTabs in KivyMD?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

How i can change color title kivymd tab:

MDTabs:
id: tabs
text_color_normal: 0, 1, 0, 1
text_color_active: 1, 0, 0, 1
color_indicator: 0.95, 0.95, 0.1, 1
everything this doesn't work, text color is remains defoult (white).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with canvas.before:

```
id:tabs
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: (1,0,0,1)
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
color:(1,0,0,1)
```